# Replace operator not working on JSON column formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I'm trying to extract the account part of email in a person column ("created by" or Author). I want to the account part so I can concatenate a text for form an URL, such as `http://somesite.com/jdoe.jpg` if, for instance, the author's email is `jdoe@email.com`.

Following the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference), I tested this:

```
"txtContent":"=replace([$Author.email], '@email.com', '.jpg')"
```

The result just displayed the full email ('jdoe@email.com'). Any reason why this doesn't work?

Incidentally, I tried an alternative with the split operator, as in:

```
"txtContent":"=split([$Author.email], '@')"
```

This return the following:

```
jdoe,
```

But I couldn't replace the separating comma either. I would appreciate any ideas on how I can get what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is some issue with `replace` operator in SharePoint JSON formatting at Microsoft end.

Instead of `replace` operator, try using `replaceAll` operator.

**Example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "='http://somesite.com/' + replaceAll([$Author.email], '@contoso.com', '.jpg')"
}
```

**Reference**: [SharePoint: Replace All Occurrences of Substring in a String using JSON Formatting](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/08/22/sharepoint-replace-all-occurrences-of-substring-in-a-string-using-json-formatting/)

**Output**:

[image]

Also, make sure you have included/shown Created By column in list view.

---

**Update**:

`replace` operator in JSON formatting also works, but you have to convert Author email to string explicitly like:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "='http://somesite.com/' + replace('' + [$Author.email] + '', '@contoso.com', '.jpg')"
}
```

Where `Author` is internal name of SharePoint default Created By column. You can get internal name of any SharePoint list column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Comment: ah, gotcha. This worked. Thanks a lot